# About examples.desktop file in ubuntu?

Tags: 20.04, .desktop

After uprading to  ubuntu 20.04 LTS,There is a file in home as **examples.desktop**
Can i delete examples.desktop file in ubuntu?
If i delete it,i need to face any issues?
what is the purpose of it?

Comment: It's a text file. Read it with `less`. `.desktop` files are used to invoke commands via mouseclick.

Comment: I am also curious: What's the purpose of it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This file is distributed on the creation of new user.

It is located in `/etc/skel/examples.desktop` and provided by the [*example-content*](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=focal&arch=any&mode=exactfilename&searchon=contents&keywords=examples.desktop) [package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/all/example-content/filelist).

You can delete it from your home folder with no future issues.